# Light wave/photon doppler effect

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, time-dilation, doppler-effect

So I understand the explanation/derivation of doppler effect from the perspective of wave crests emission being stretched out as the source moves. But how does this work from the photon point of view?

a) If a red photon is emitted at t = 0 s, and as source moves away, at t = 2 s, another red photon is emitted, wouldn't the observer receive two red photons with the 2nd photon delayed (if ignoring expansion of space)? How does the doppler effect occur here?

b) If as the source moves away, only 1 photon is emitted, again ignoring the space expansion, would there be doppler effect seen by the observer when that single photon arrives?

Comment: I have an answer here on the difference between photons and light waves https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428810/

Comment: Individual photons have a well defined energy. That energy is reduced by redshift and increased by Doppler blueshift. The average detection rate of photons (for a constant emitter power) is also reduced by Doppler redshift and increased by blueshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the photon picture, the Doppler effect manifests itself in two ways. Assuming the source and observer are moving away from each other,

1. The rate at which the photons arrive is reduced. This happens for the reason you noted: the second photon is delayed, so the time difference between the arrival of two photons is greater than the time difference between emitted photons as measured by the source. You also need to account for time dilation to get the correct factor by which the photon arrival rate is reduced.
2. The photon energy that the observer measures is less than that measured by the source. Or in other words, the observer measures a longer wavelength. Here is one way to show this in special relativity. Restricting ourselves to one temporal and one spatial dimension for simplicity, the four-momentum of a photon with energy $E$, according to the source, is
   $$\begin{bmatrix}E/c \\ E/c \end{bmatrix}.$$
   The photon [four-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) in the observer's reference frame is this vector, [Lorentz boosted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Proper_transformations) by observer velocity $v=\beta c>0$:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}\gamma & -\gamma\beta \\ -\gamma\beta & \gamma \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}E/c \\ E/c \end{bmatrix}=\sqrt\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}\begin{bmatrix}E/c \\ E/c \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}E'/c \\ E'/c \end{bmatrix}$$
   so according to the observer, the photon energy is $E'=\sqrt\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}E<E.$

If the source emits a single photon, the observer detects a single photon, with a wavelength higher than that measured by the source.

Comment: Thanks Ruk! Is the doppler effect just a consequence of Lorentz transformation?

Comment: @ABC It can be derived using the Lorentz transformation alone, so yes, I would say that's an accurate statement.

Comment: Sorry that was posted before I finished typing.
For scenario 1, I guess my confusion comes from, when people use wave crest to explain it, they say interval between wave crest is stretched out, therefore "wavelength" increases, and thus blue light becomes red light. In the case of the two photons, the delay between their arrival does not mean each photon themselves get stretched, which isn't what doppler effect says. But of course, according to your answer to 2, each photon itself does get stretched as well...

Comment: Setting aside whether it makes sense to speak of photons getting stretched, the argument for the change in the arrival rate of photons (effect #1 above) doesn't say that photons themselves remain unchanged when you go to a difference reference frame. If it helps, you can think of photons as very short pulses of light. The observer finds that (1) the pulses arrive at a reduced rate, and (2) the pulses are longer. Both are consistent with the Doppler effect and the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Why do you think standard textbooks always use wave crest to explain the doppler effect and never photon view?

Comment: There are probably some that use the photon picture too. I think the wave picture is easier to explain to students new to special relativity, because it doesn't require concepts like four-momentum and how it transforms under a Lorentz boost. You don't even strictly need the Lorentz transformation, just time dilation and length contraction.

Comment: yeah I guess my issue with the wave crest view is that it kind of gives the impression that each crest is a photon (or maybe that's just my misinterpretation). I've had a similar question before physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733487/… . If you wouldn't mind shed some insight on my misconception there -- how to derive that using photon view? And what determines (in the galaxy's frame) the interval between two successive photons? Thanks!